# Migrate and synchronize local SQL data to SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

Is there any way to migrate and synchronize data between an on-premise SQL database and SQL Azure database apart from sync framework?

The sync framework works fine for small databases, but when it comes to large databases its not working. Is there any possible way to migrate and synchronize using change datacapture and SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to clarify what you mean by "its not working". Are you having issues during the initial sync or incremental sync? what's the sync direction required for your sync? upload/download/bidirectional? do you get an error?

there are many ways to do the migration,

for synchronization, apart from Sync Framework, you may also look at Sql Azure Data Sync (largely based on Sync Framework too).

and yes, you can use Change Data Capture and SSIS if you want but note that Sql Azure doesnt have the same Change Data Capture feature as Sql Server so you'll be fine using CDC and SSIS for on-premise to Sql Azure sync only. You have to figure out another way to do change tracking on the Sql Azure side.

Comment: hey june sync direction i m using is biderctional.i m getting an time out error.

Comment: have you looked at this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/09/24/how-to-sync-large-sql-server-databases-to-sql-azure.aspx you need to set the MemoryDataCacheSize, ApplicationTransactionSize and the CommandTimeout to avoid timeouts and throttling